# Php из функции загрузить класс

Tags: php

```
class hello{
public function echo()
{
return 'omg';
}
}

function world()
{
global $a;
$a = new hello();
}

world();
$a->echo();
```

Есть идеи как можно такое реализовать правильно?

Comment: Это даже не велосипед, это самокат :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Manitikyl](/users/3967/manitikyl)](/users/3967/manitikyl), вы пытаетесь реализовать что-то вроде очень-очень легковесного [контейнера Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) (создать сервис по его имени). Могу посоветовать две штуки:

- Обзавестись автозагрузчиком (`spl_autoload_register()`), который позволит абстрагироваться от инклюдов
- Завести типичный реест (Registry) и сохранять все туда. В результате получится такая штука:

...

```
class Autoloader
{
    public function loadClass($className)
    {
        // произвольная реализация
    }
}
```

...

```
class Registry
{
    protected static $storage = array();
    public static function set($name, $item)
    {
        static::$storage[$name] = $item;
    }
    public static function get($name)
    {
        return static::$storage[$name];
    }
    public static function has($name)
    {
        return isset(static::$storage[$name]);
    }
}
```

...

```
class Di
{
    protected $registryPrefix = 'di:services:';
    public function createService($className)
    {
        $instance = ;
        Registry::set($this->registryPrefix . $className, new $className);
    }
    public function getService($className)
    {
        if (!Registry::has($this->registryPrefix . $className)) {
            $this->createService($className);
        }
        return Registry::get($this->registryPrefix . $className);
    }
}
```

index.php

```
spl_autoload_register([new Autoloader, 'loadClass']);
Registry::set('di', new DI);
```

любой друго файл

```
// создали и забыли
Registry::get('di')->createService('\App\Services\TextDecorator');
// создали и получили
$decoder = Registry::get('di')->createService('\App\Services\ImageDecoder');
// получили тот же инстанс, что и в первый раз, не создавая лишний объект
$decoder = Registry::get('di')->createService('\App\Services\ImageDecoder')
```

Comment: ну да ток только не 'легковесного контейнера Symfony', а фабрику классов.

Comment: @Manitikyl, фабрика не сохраняет так или иначе инстансы, и вообще задачи создания у нее несколько другие

Comment: @Etki, все зависит от реализации 'данной фабрики', в любом случае решил я сам задачу, но за новую идейку + и закрываем диалог.

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотите получить таким образом? А вообще, как-то так:

```
function world()
{
    return new hello();
}

$a = world();
$a->echo();
```

Comment: я вроде описал задачу) Описывать слишком долго и нудно, но цель вроде ясна. В любом случае уже сам допер как. Спс за отзыв.

Comment: @Manitikyl, не, уж постарайтесь как-нибудь описать.

Comment: В любом случае задумайтесь, зачем вам нужна отдельная функция для создания класса. Хотя, может я чего-то не понимаю в этом вашем программировании.

Comment: Заинтриговали и сбежали… Не надо так!…

Comment: Интриги и расследования! Код в коде. Только на #хэшкод :)

Comment: @Etki, @jackrv, @rnddev, @andreyqin, Короче мой пытливый ум решил поставить для себя задачу, написать функцию, с одним параметром (название класса) world(myclass), функция не возвращает никакого результата, функция должна была создать глобальную переменную типа $GLOBALS['_myclass']  и создать в нее экземпляр этого класса, который как бы прописан ранее вне функции. инклудить еще раз в функцию данный класс - запрещено. вот собстна задача) пошаманил понакрутил в итоге получилось :<

Comment: просто не понятно почему я прихожу к вам с определенной проблемной задачей (найти ее решение), а вы говорите - зачем эта задача, нам нужен результат выполнения данной задачи. а задачу и проблему я вроде доступно описывал. Конечно, судя по статистике у каждой проблемы есть как минимум 7 способов ее решения, но для общего развития интересовал именно данный метод.